# I am getting this error int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'set'

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Why I am getting this error I am creating a triangle

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'set'
```

Code snippet:

```
a, b, c = input().split()
print(f'A : {a}, B : {b}, C : {c}')
sisi_terpanjang = {a}
sisi_pertama = {b}
sisi_kedua = {c}
if int(sisi_terpanjang)**2 == int(sisi_pertama)**2 + int(sisi_kedua)**2:
  print("segitiga siku-siku")
if int(sisi_terpanjang)**2 < int(sisi_pertama)**2 + int(sisi_kedua)**2:
  print("segitiga lancip")
if int(sisi_terpanjang)**2 > int(sisi_pertama)**2 + int(sisi_kedua)**2:
  print("segitiga tumpul")
```

and the error in cell:

```
if int(sisi_terpanjang)**2 == int(sisi_pertama)**2 + int(sisi_kedua)**2:
```

Comment: `sisi_pertama = {b}` Yup, that's a set.  Why are you trying to call `int()` on a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is because you're trying to convert sets/list `{}` to integers using `int()`, which is not valid. You can simply set `sisi_xxx` to int like this. Here is the modified code:

```
a, b, c = input().split()
print(f'A : {a}, B : {b}, C : {c}')
sisi_terpanjang = int(a)
sisi_pertama = int(b)
sisi_kedua = int(c)
if sisi_terpanjang**2 == sisi_pertama**2 + sisi_kedua**2:
    print("segitiga siku-siku")
if sisi_terpanjang**2 < sisi_pertama**2 + sisi_kedua**2:
    print("segitiga lancip")
if sisi_terpanjang**2 > sisi_pertama**2 + sisi_kedua**2:
    print("segitiga tumpul")
```

[You can check on my kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/edgarsitohang/triangle)

Comment: Ah, finally it worked, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

`{}` defines a list. Just remove them and use such as

```
sisi_terpanjang = a
sisi_pertama = b
sisi_kedua = c
```

Comment: Better yet would be `sisi_terpanjang = int(a)`, do avoid making that conversion over and over and over.

Comment: @TimRoberts, yes, but I don't know how he goes about writing his code.